# Minimum of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{3}{1+(h-x)^2}$, for $0\leq x \leq h$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

Find the minimum of the function
$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{3}{1+(h-x)^2}$, for $0\leq x \leq h$
Proof that the solution can be expressed as:
1. There exists a $δ>0$ so that for $0\leq h \leq \delta$, minimum occurs at $x=0$
2. For $h>δ$ minimum occurs when $x$ is in the interval $(0, h)$

For your convenience, this problem, slightly modified, is presented as Problem 2 "easy to be solved" in the book V.M. Tikhomirov, "Stories about maxima and minima" (story VIII, Newtons aerodymnamic problem). The above expression of the problem is a (counter-)translation in English from my Greek edition of the book.

Comment: Dear Satish,in your proof the conclusion 0<=h<=δ leads to h-δ<=0

Comment: @satish: Dear Satish, at the first part the inequality 0<h<δ implies h-δ<0 which in turn implies x<0 which is not correct

Comment: the equality happens only when $(h-\delta)$ is greater than or equal to zero, but $(h-\delta)$ is less than or equal to zero and thus goes to prove that $(h-\delta) = x = 0$.